# Google cloud compute: Traccar Installation

Tags: firewall, cloud, google, ubuntu-18.04

I have a Google Cloud instance that I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on with traccar installation on port '8082'.

I cannot open the tomcat and deployed application in the browser from the Google Cloud instance even after adding the firewall rule to open the traffic on '8082' port is not working from my laptop (i.e. internet)

I have spent hours finding the solution but somehow its just not working.

Below is a snippet of the 'netstat -plnt' and iptables:

[iptables and netstat -plnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wriSJ.png)

Below is the configuration of my firewall:

[Firewall Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fufo7.png)

I have set my external ip address to a static ip as well.  I tried to recreate a network but couldn't find a way to switch from default network to new network.

Comment: Your netstat output doesn't show anything listening on 8082.  Did you start it?

Comment: Yes I did start the application. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Your application isn't listening anywhere. Check its logs (e.g. catalina.out) to find out why.

Comment: Hi Michael, thats the issue that I am trying to resolve. I have opened the port as shown and the application is starting but application is not listening anywhere. There are no errors on application startup

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use NetCat to test the networking / firewall portion and make sure the port 8082 is reachable from outside.

Just run: `nc -l -p 8082`

I'm not familiar with Traccar, but I found this [page](https://www.traccar.org/forums/topic/traccar-server-not-listening-on-configured-ports-for-devices/) that might be of some help.